# how to fixed the nav bar inside wrapper

Tags: html, css

i want to fix the nav bar at the top of the wrapper when i scrolling down. 
but when i put the position: fixed in the #nav ul , the nav bar go beyong the wrapper. 
here is my html code , inside the nav bar should be inside the wrapper

```
> <DOCTYPE html>
> 
> <html lang="en">
> 
> <head>     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">    
> <title>KDU Music</title>   <meta charset="utf-8"> </head>
> 
> 
> <body> <div id="title">
>            <p><h1>Welcome to KDU MUSIC CENTER</h1></p>
>           </div>
>       
> 
> <div id= "wrapper"> <div id="nav">        <ul>
>            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
>            <li><a href="findoutmore.php">Find out more</a></li>
>            <li><a href="offer.html">Offer</a></li>
>            <li><a href="credit.html">Credit</a></li>
>            <li><a href="#">Admin</a></li>
>            <li><a href="wireframe.html">WireFrame</a></li>        </ul>   </div>
> 
> <div id="content">
> 
>   <div class = "first">       <p><h1>123</h1></p>         <p><h1>123</h1></p>
>       <p><h1>123</h1></p>         <p><h1>123</h1></p>     </div>          <div class =
> "first">
>           <p><h1>123</h1></p>         <p><h1>123</h1></p>         <p><h1>123</h1></p>         <p><h1>123</h1></p>
>           </div>  
>           <p><h1>123</h1></p>     <p><h1>123</h1></p>     <p><h1>123</h1></p>     <p><h1>123</h1></p>     <p><h1>123</h1></p>     <p><h1>123</h1></p>
>   <p><h1>123</h1></p>     <p><h1>123</h1></p>     <p><h1>123</h1></p>
>   <p><h1>123</h1></p>     <p><h1>123</h1></p>
> 
> </div> </div>
> 
> </body>
> 
> </html>
```

here is my css

```
body{background-color  :    #C0C0C0;
     margin : 0px; 

}

#nav ul {   background-color: #333;
        list-style-type: none;
        text-align: center;
        top : 0px;
        width : 100% ;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;


        }

#nav li { 
      display: inline;


}

#nav li a {

     color: white;
     padding: 20px 30px;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size : 40px;    
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

#wrapper { margin : 3% 5%;
           background-color: #FFF5EE;
           min-width : 400px;
           } 


#title {text-align : center;
       font-size : 30px;
       text-decoration: underline;
}

#content {padding : 3%;}

.first{border: 5px solid;}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To fix the navigation menu to the wrapper, the wrapper element will need a relative position.

```
#wrapper {
    position:relative;
}

#nav ul {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: When you scroll, are you changing the position of the wrapper? With the above changes, your navigation will stick to your wrapper, if you were to move the wrapper element when you scroll, then the navigation will move with it.

Comment: when i added the position :fixed in to the #nav ul , the nav ran out of the wrapper as the image shown above..
and yes , the nav stick should stick at in the top my wrapper...
what i try to do is put the nav bar back in the wrapper

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the z-index. With the z-index is it possible to fix this. I had the same problem at my website last week